# Streaming Dailymotion video on android gives 404 error

Tags: android, html, intel-xdk

I am trying to embed a Dailymotion video into an android app.
The app is standard HTML5, I am using Intel XDK as IDE and build tool.

I am using this code to embed the video on the HTML page:

```
<div class="panel" data-title="La piramide di fango" id="07032016">
    <iframe frameborder="0" width="100%" height="100%" src="http://www.dailymotion.com/embed/video/x40q11y"></iframe>
</div>
```

The issue is that when I am trying to debug the app on the real device I am currently getting:

***Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)***

However if I try to load the same URL by a desktop browser, it works without issues.

The app has the necessary permissions like:

FULL INTERNET ACCESS

Just another information: if I try to run the app by the INTEL APP PREVIEW, it seems working fine...

Answer (score 0):

**Try adding the src content on load of page via java script**